How to place an image on top of another image (in the target image 2D texture space)?
I would like to place an image on top of an equilateral HDRI environment texture, like this:

I would also like to be able to manipulate the placed image (move around in the large image's XY space, scale and rotate).
(I could do this of course in a paint program, but then it would be already fixed in size and position.)
Trying to to this the following way is not working as the manipulation is not in the large image 2D texture space:

Also, the small image is mirrored on the horizon line despite it is set to clip.
I can't find a way to do this. Is there a way and if yes how?
